# How do I create a shopping cart rule for A SET of products

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I run an online delivery restaurant. I want to create a shopping car rule (or several rules, nevermind) generating the following discounts:

- If you buy 1 starter + 1 main course + 1 desert, you get a $5 discount;
- If you either buy 1 starter + 1 main course *or* 1 main course + 1 desert, you get a $3 discount.

Please note that "Starters", "Main courses" and "Deserts" are categories in my store. So if you have the following cart:

- 3 starters
- 3 main courses
- 2 deserts
- 1 bottle of wine

I want you to get a **total discount of $13**, i.e. $5 for each 3-courses menu + $3 for the 2-courses menu. (The "Wine" category is not included in the rule and does not generate any discount.)

I have searched everywhere without getting a satisfying answer. The closest ones I have found were these 2, but they did not solve all the problems:

- [Is this coupon possible? Get fixed amount off for each 5 items from a specific category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/is-this-coupon-possible-get-fixed-amount-off-for-each-5-items-from-a-specific-c/40618#40618) [2nd answer]
- [Cart/Catalog Price rule for a set of products only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53340/cart-catalog-price-rule-for-a-set-of-products-only)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want a flat $5 (or $3) off the entire cart total, you should be able to do this with something like this:

Click the grid icon to select your category
[image: click the grid icon to select your category]

Leave the Actions rules blank, and switch the Apply to Fixed amount discount, and set Stop Further Rule Processing to No
[image: Leave the Actions rules blank, and switch the Apply to Fixed amount discount, and set Stop Further Rule Processing to No]

Make sure No Coupon is selected
[image: Make sure No Coupon is selected]

As long as you keep the conditions separated out like this, you should only get the promotion if all three/two items are in your cart.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this was what I had originally set up, and it systematically generates way too high discounts. For example: 

- for a "3-courses menu", you get 23$ of discount instead of only 5$;

- for 1 menu with main course + desert, you get -6$ instead of -3$;
- for 1 menu with starter + main course, you get -5$ instead of -3$.
(I have no idea why there is a difference in the discount amount between the last 2 options.)

Comment: This answer will give a $5 discount on every item in the cart if those conditions are met.